# Reloading a Tab in Firefox until success

Tags: firefox, http, firefox-extensions

Is there any plugin for Firefox which reloads a tab every “x” amount of time but stops reloading after the first successful request (HTTP status code 2xx)?

Answer (score 2):

You might try [Mr Uptime](http://mruptime.pingdom.com). However it looks like it might not be compatible with the latest version of Firefox. Also I haven't tried it for myself, so I'm not sure if it loads into a tab like you want, but it at least seems to cover your other requirements based on their feature list.

[image]